# Issues in creating custom multi project MVC 4 web application template vs2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, vsix, project-template

I am working on custom multi solution project structure having
1. 4 class library projects
2. One MVC 4 Web application.

I have built multi solution structure into VSIX package.Till here everything is fine.

Upon VSIX installation,I can see my multi solution project type in Visual studio 2012 projects.

When I try to create on out of it, it will display a following error while creating for every images present in "\Content\themes\base\images" in MVC 4 application

"The file ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png could not be found within the project templates.Continuing to run, but resulting project may not be build properly"

Although I have all the images as a apart of WEb Project templates.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the images within the project template have `Build Action` set to *Content* and `Include in VSIX` set to *True*. Also, verify in your vstemplate file that the image is included as a *ProjectItem* and within the proper folder.

Or, if you have JQuery UI included as a Nuget package you can just install the package as a part of your template. Then, you don't even need to include the images with your vsix. http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/packages-in-visual-studio-templates